# How to combine including and excluding functionality in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Part of my collection is as follows:

```
# Order1 
{
 "countries": [
  {
    "code":"us"
  }
 ],
 "cities": {
  "includes":["a", "b"],
  "excludes":[]
 }
}


# Order2 
{
 "countries": [
  {
    "code":"all"
  }
 ],
 "cities": {
  "includes":["all"],
  "excludes":["x"]
 }
}

# Order3
{
 "countries": [
  {
    "code":"all"
  }
 ],
 "cities": {
  "includes":["all"],
  "excludes":[]
 }
}
```

How do I query to get both including and excluding orders correctly?

#### Example 1:

```
URL parameters: country=us&city=a 
Expected result: Order1, Order2, Order3
```

#### Example 2:

```
URL parameters: country=us&city=x
Expected result: Order3
```

#### Example 3:

```
URL parameters: country=de&city=z
Expected result: Order2, Order3
```

One of things I've tried is similar to this:

```
           $and: [{
                    $or: [{
                        'countries.code': 'all'
                    }, {
                        'countries.code': URL_PARAMETER_FOR_COUNTRY
                    }]
                }, {
                $and: [{
                        $or: [{
                            'cities.includes': 'all'
                        }, {
                            'cities.includes': URL_PARAMETER_FOR_CITY
                        }]
                    },

                    {
                        'cities.excludes': {
                            $ne: URL_PARAMETER_FOR_CITY
                        }
                    }]

            }]
```

Comment: Please elaborate which orders should be *correctly* included and excluded?

Comment: I've added some expected results @AlexBlex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were basically on the right track but you're getting confused with the "nesting" of logic and the usage of operators like [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/). **All** MongoDB query arguments are *already* an "AND* condition, so there is generally no need to specify this.

Also when you have more than one condition for an [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) on exactly the same field, it's a lot cleaner to write this with [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) instead:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "countries.code": { "$in": ["all",COUNTRY_PARAM] },
    "cities.includes": { "$in": ["all",CITY_PARAM] },
    "cities.excludes": { "$ne": CITY_PARAM }
})
```

Even if you wanted to roll in "mutliple" tests for the "excludes" such as an "all" value, then just apply the "list non-equivalent" statement which is [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/):

```js
db.collection.find({
    "countries.code": { "$in": ["all",COUNTRY_PARAM] },
    "cities.includes": { "$in": ["all",CITY_PARAM] },
    "cities.excludes": { "$nin": ["all",CITY_PARAM }
})
```

That meets all described combinations of returning the matching documents.

The reason query arguments are an "AND" condition without specifying it is because generally that is what people mean, hence it makes the expression much more simplified than the terse representation, and far less confusing.

AND with AND means "AND" on **all** conditions, so no need to partition.

Comment: Hi @Blakes Seven, thanks for this explanatory answer. I truly loved it. Clear and clean. However, I was unable to implement this solution to my code. Actually, I implemented but it is not working as expected. Expected as I explained at my question. Simply, this `"countries.code": { "$in": ["all",COUNTRY_PARAM]` is not returning anything even though it has `['all']` as a value. Any idea on what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: @scaryguy Personally I would construct at least the "query" document and possibly even just components and "log" what is going in there to make sure it is actually what you expect. Also there is possibly something else you are doing that is not an "exact" representation of the sample here. But of course this works for me with the same expected outputs as mentioned in your question.

Comment: I agree on this possibility: `Also there is possibly something else you are doing that is not an "exact" representation of the sample here`. I'm just trying to figure it out. I'll update here when I catch something or I can't :) I think I need some time. Thank you very much for your help. Truly appreciated.

Comment: Finally, I did it :) Your code was working as it's supposed to do. But I had some issues about my existing data. For example, I didn't have "all" keyword in some cases. Thank you very much Blakes!